How to fetch data from the two plugin's data on the frontend?
I am making a simple project portal where a user can apply for projects, now I want, if the user applies for any project, it should be visible on the "My projects" page in his/her account.
I am using "SIMPLE JOB BOARD" plugin to post projects.
How can I implement this ?? there is a unique user ID for every user and a unique project-ID so can I use it in some way to get some shortcode and show on front end?

You'll have to figure out how to query the 'Simple Job Board' plugin's data - does it use Custom Post-Types, does it use custom data tables, etc... ...the solution here is to figure out what to query and how and then output that in a shortcode.

Thanks @TonyDjukic

I would suggest you asking this question in the dedicated plugin forum. They might be able to answer this question more precisely, as the developers are active in the forum (from what I can see).
Alternatively this add-on should do the trick - it's featured in the plugin description as well.
